# Joomla 3.3 modules not sending e-mails to different domains

Tags: email, joomla, module, contacts

I'm trying to confugure a contact form module to send the forms to custom e-mails other than the administrator's, wich is from the same domain as Joomla installation.

When I configure the module to send to administrator's e-mail, it works fine. However when I input other e-mail adresses from different domains to be the recipient, the e-mail isn't sent.

I already tested with Breezing Forms and B2J Contact, and this problem happened with both of them so I suppose it's a Joomla configuration problem. Using B2J Contact allows me to add two e-mail recipients, so I tested using the administrator's as main and the other from a different domain as copy, and I receive the e-mail only on the main recipient.

I'm using PHP Mail as the send method and my Joomla version is 3.3.0.

I've been researching for days and can't seem to find a solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the send mail method to SMTP and placing the right port number, which I got from my host provider.